# javascript Validation: removing the error msg by a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox and I used JS to see check if the text box is empty or not.
if it is empty a error message will appear under the text box.

Now when I do go back and enter text into the empty textbox the error message stays. how can I re-check if the user entered any text and then automatically remove the error link.

```html
<label for="last_name_field">Last Name <abbr title="Required">*</abbr></label>
                    <input type="text" id="last_name_field" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" onblur="validateLN()">
```

```js
 function validateLN() {
   if (document.form.lastname.value == "") { //create an error message
     var msg = " Last Name cannot be blank";
     //call the display error function
     displayError(document.form.lastname, msg);
   }



 }


 function displayError(element, msg) {
   if (element.nextSibling.tagName == "SPAN" && element.nextSibling.textContent.trim == msg.trim) {
     return;
   } else {

     var msgElement = document.createElement("span");
     msgElement.textContent = msg;
     msgElement.style.color = "red";
     element.parentNode.insertBefore(msgElement, element.nextSibling);
     element.style.border = "solid 1px red";
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the error from within the `onchange` event of your textbox.

```
function validateLN() {
    if (document.form.lastname.value == "") { //create an error message
        var msg = " Last Name cannot be blank";
        //call the display error function
        displayError(document.form.lastname, msg);
    }
}

document.form.lastname.onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('errorMsg').remove();
}

function displayError(element, msg) {
    if (element.nextSibling.tagName == "SPAN" && element.nextSibling.textContent.trim == msg.trim) {
        return;
    } else {
        var msgElement = document.createElement("span");
        msgElement.id = 'errorMsg';
        msgElement.textContent = msg;
        msgElement.style.color = "red";
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(msgElement, element.nextSibling);
        element.style.border = "solid 1px red";
    }
}
```

Or simply keep it there and toggle its `display` value:

```
var msgElement = document.createElement("span");
msgElement.id = 'errorMsg';
msgElement.textContent = msg;
msgElement.style.color = "red";
msgElement.style.display = 'none';
element.parentNode.insertBefore(msgElement, element.nextSibling);
element.style.border = "solid 1px red";

function validateLN() {
    if (document.form.lastname.value == "") { //create an error message
        var msg = " Last Name cannot be blank";
        //call the display error function
        document.getElementById('errorMsg').style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

document.form.lastname.onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('errorMsg').style.display = 'none';
}
```